# Code to ask for user string, then display the output

Tags: python, strings

```
# printstring.py
# 7/8/2016

import sys

# ask for user input
s_string = input('Enter a string: ')

# if no string, then exit()
if s_string == '':
    sys.exit()

# display the output
print(s_string)
```

Also wondering how to get "raw" input and output the text properly formatted with line breaks, etc. Also looking for general feedback and tips for improvement.

Comment: The second part of your question ("raw" io) belongs on Stack Overflow instead.

Answer (score 2):

**More elegant way to check if a string is empty**
[Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573244/most-elegant-way-to-check-if-the-string-is-empty-in-python)

```
if not s_string:
    sys.exit()
```

**You don't need a sys.exit(), just let the program exit on its own.**

```
if s_string:
    print(s_string)

# the program will exit here anyway.
```

`sys.exit()` has some side-effects like killing the python interpreter, which might have some undesirable effects. [Read here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73663/terminating-a-python-script)

**You don't even need to check if the string is empty**

```
print(s_string) # If string is empty, will print nothing except for a newline.
```

**Name `s_string` just `s` or `string`**.

It doesn't detract from the readability of the code, and makes it more pretty and easier to type(and read)

**Most people tend to prefer double quotes `"` for string literals** [Read Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56011/single-quotes-vs-double-quotes-in-python)

Comment: `print(s_string)` will print a blank line if `s_string` is empty.

Comment: Oh, indeed! Thanks for pointing that out, will edit.